# MySQL Query to find repeats in multiple months

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find accounts in the month of November, who have repeated in either of the prior months till August (Oct, Sept, Aug).

For example, account 1243 is in November, the search should come back with the account if it was seen in Aug, Sept or Oct, if not, it doesn't display the account. Data is just 3columns, ID, Account and Date. Below is my query:

```
SELECT  distinct account 
FROM `nash` 
WHERE `date`=201211 
AND account IN (SELECT account 
                FROM `nash` where `date`=201208 
                OR account IN 
                (SELECT account 
                 FROM `nash` where `date`=201209) 
                OR account IN 
                (SELECT account 
                 FROM `nash` where `date`=201210));
```

Also note, there are dates after November as well in the same table and should not be included in the results.

Please let me know what I can do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `OR` logic is including anything that shows up in `201209` or `201210`. The `OR` has lower precedence than `AND`, so your logic is ending up like this:

- `date=201211 AND account IN (SELECT account FROM nash where date=201208)`, *or*
- `date=201209`, *or*
- `date=201210`

You can get rid of the `OR` logic (and make the query faster because there's just one subquery scan) by changing it to this:

```
SELECT  distinct account 
FROM `nash` 
WHERE `date`=201211 
  AND account IN (
    SELECT account
    FROM `nash`
    WHERE `date` IN (201208, 201209, 201210)
  )
```

Comment: This is awesome, that worked flawlessly. I appreciate the info!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `nash` a WHERE month( date ) =10
AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM nash b WHERE a.account = b.account AND month( b.date ) <10)
```

Note that you may want to change month(date) to the full date if your data in in more than one year